# OnRobot RG2 Gripper on UR3 with TCP communication

Tags: robotic-arm

I am using a UR3 Robot with OnRobot RG2 Gripper. I have successfully connected the robot to my computer via Ethernet and i am able to send move commands and receive data successfully with Python. But the commands for RG2 Gripper provided in the manual are not working. I can send commands to the gripper via teaching pendant (by command RG2) but not through my computer via Ethernet. Has anyone had a solution to this problem ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I had the discussion with Robotiq about the same thing for their grippers when I started working with them, and as I understand it, the UR Caps commands are not installed as commands in the robot, but they are instead defined in each new program. If you read the .script files for a program created with a UR Caps command, the commands used will be defined before the robot program itself.
I have yet to try it myself, but possibly you could define these functions yourself first and then send it?

But, for Robotiq there are more options available. For OnRobot I don't know.

Addition:
I did some tests on the VM simulator, I just started a .script file from a program I previously did. Works like a charm. So for open and close scripts of the OnRobot, I guess it is fine.

```
    import socket
    import time
    HOST = "10.0.2.15"    # The remote host
    PORT = 30002              # The same port as used by the server
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    print("Starting Program")
    f=open("/home/ur/Desktop/TestScript.script", "r")
    s.send (f.read() + "/n")
    data = s.recv(1024)
    s.close()
    print ("Closed connection and received data")
```

Also got interested in how to send a value without having to open the script, like a width. I'm quite new to Python, but an example, adding all this instead of the f.open above:

```
    width = 11 # 11 just and example, user input or something works as well..
    with open("/home/ur/Desktop/TestScript.script", "r") as in_file:
        buf = in_file.readlines()
    i=0
    with open("/home/ur/Desktop/TestScriptOut.script", "w+") as out_file:
        for line in buf:
            if i == 0: # Notice that this will add var_1 in the second line
                line = line + "  global var_1 = %s\n" % width
            out_file.write(line)
            i=i+1
    out_file.close()
    f = open("/home/ur/Desktop/TestScriptOut.script", "r")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here use this library I developed to communicate with onRobot grippers with the Universal Robots (robots) through the standard m8 tool connector.

git@github.com:RyanPaulMcKenna/onRobot.git

https://pypi.org/project/onRobot/

Can pip install like so:

```bash
pip install onRobot
```

and use like so:

```py
import onRobot.gripper as gripper

# Default id is zero, if you have multiple grippers, 
# see logs in UR Teach Pendant to know which is which :)
rg_id = 0
rg_gripper = gripper.RG2(rg_id)

rg_width = rg_gripper.get_rg_width()
pregrasp_width = 100

# force and width units described in onRobot RG2 Manual
target_width = 15.66
target_force = 40.00

if (rg_wdith == pregrasp_width):
    rg_gripper.rg_grip(target_width, target_force)

epsilon = 0.05 # Just an example of reasonable error may not be realistic. 
grip_success = abs(rg_gripper.get_rg_width() - target_width) < epsilon
```